# "He rolled his toilet things into his housewife"

Tags: etymology, terminology, history, synecdoche

From C.S. Forester's [Hornblower and the Hotspur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hornblower_and_the_Hotspur):

> [The naval captain] rolled his toilet things into his ***housewife*** and tied the tapes.

[ODO does provide a second definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/housewife) for *housewife* which clarifies this usage:

> **/ˈhʌzɪf/** a small case for needles, thread, and other small sewing items.

Besides its curious pronunciation, I'd like to know how *housewife* came to mean the above. Any other related information will also be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably similar to the reason those behind-your-back-in-bed pillows are called [*husbands*](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/search/search.aspx?order_num=-1&sstr=husband+pillow&dim=1&nty=1&).

Comment: Is the pronunciation that much more curious than the nautical pronunciations of *forecastle, boatswain, mainsail, northeast*?

Comment: @PeterShor If it is strictly a naval term, perhaps not. I don't know if it is.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=housewife&searchmode=none) relates *hussy* to *housewife*, so perhaps the pronunciation shouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: @PeterShor: 'Northeast' is not pronounced 'north-east'?

Comment: @Mitch Fo'c'sle, bo's'n, nor'east.

Comment: Thanks coleopterist.  I found many more examples in historic documentation of soldiers' belongings including a quote from Rootschat.com in response to "What is a Housewife?": ***"I actually have a small hussif made of khaki cloth.
It was amongst a lot of other bits of sewing equipment in a sewing box I bought in bric-a -brac shop some years ago.
I've often wondered about the soldier to belonged to."***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pronunciation of *housewife* is complicated. According to *OED 1* two forms of compounds with *hus* existed in ME, one with and one without a connective /e/, thus: *husbond*, *husebond* (*OED 1* is unsure why). In the following couple of centuries, the two forms *husewif* and *huswif* diverged further in pronunciation:

- That without the /e/ elided the /w/ and shortened the vowel in the initial syllable, which developed regularly into /ʌ/; the second syllable was destressed (the ordinary English pattern) and consequently shortened the vowel, yielding such orthographic forms as *hussif*, *hussive* and *huzzy*, which was until recently the ordinary pronunciation for the primary sense of “mistress of the house”.
- that with the /e/ maintained the long first syllable and the /w/, and then developed regularly into /haʊswaɪf/, with two long vowels, reflected in the modern spelling. According to *OED 1*, this pronunciation was literary and dialectal into the 18th century, used only of transferred senses; but

> the analytical form with long vowel, *hūsewīf, hūswīf, houswif, housewife*, continued in use and became frequent in Sense 1 in the 16th c., esp. when the shortened *hŭswĭf* began to lose caste, through its depreciatory sense [hussy]. But many still pronounce *huswif, hussif* in Sense 1, even when they write *housewife*.

The connection between *hussy* and *housewife* has long been lost, [spelling pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_pronunciation) has reinforced what was once a dialectal form, and the calling itself has “lost caste”; so people encounter the word today mostly in writing and pronounce it the way it looks — as they do other words, such as *grindstone* and those nautical terms from the Age of Sail which Peter Shor mentions.

As for the transferred sense of *housewife* as a small case — this was originally a first-aid kit for spot repairs carried by the *housewife* herself:

> To bring whatever he had to say, into so small a compass that ... it might be rolled up in my mother's housewife. —Sterne, *Tristram Shandy*

Answer (score 1):

It perhaps doesn’t take too much imagination to see that in the absence of their spouses men might give the name *housewife* to an object that performs at least one of the roles of their loved ones. The OED’s earliest citation for this use is dated 1735.

Answer (score 0):

For pronunciation, the OED has (in sense 4, the one in question here):

> Brit. /ˈhʌzɪf/ , U.S. /ˈhəzəf/

Comment: I don’t understand the notion of a stress schwa in English.  I might buy /ˈhʌzəf/, but the other doesn’t make sense to me.