# Why does the pronunciation of the word "wife" [waif] change in the word "midwifery" [ˈmɪdˌwɪfərɪ]?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I recently found out that the word *wife* is pronounced differently in the following examples:

*wife* [waif] / *midwife* [midwaif] / but *midwifery* [ˈmɪdˌwɪfərɪ]

This appears to be another inconsistency of English phonetics. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I've always pronounced the -wi- syllable the same in *midwife* and *midwifery*. Merriam-Webster lists both /-wi-/ and /-wī-/ as possible pronunciations. If the /whiff/ pronunciation bothers you, just use the other one. :)

Comment: No, this isn't an inconsistency of English phonetics. It's a consistency of English phonology. In _wife_ and _midwife_ the last syllable has primary stress, and therefore /ay/ can appear in it. In _midwifery_ the second syllable does not have primary stress, and therefore is reduced to /ɪ/. This is an automatic consequence of English syllable-timing, which lengthens syllables with primary stress and allows all possible English vowels to occur in such syllables. In unstressed or secondarily stressed syllables, the range of possible vowels is much smaller.

Comment: @Marthaª: In the UK it seems to me that in many cases where people place the stress on different syllables, it turns out that [the "non-standard" version is American](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/8305645/The-conTROversy-over-changing-pronunciations.html). But if I heard someone say *mid-WIFE-ery* (which I probably never have), I'd tend to assume they invented it themselves by extrapolation from the written form, *not* because they heard other people using it. Presumably though, you *do* hear others using it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, until today, I've never heard it pronounced any other way. If I had heard someone say it (without any other indication they were using a different dialect from my own) I might have thought they'd invented themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: (1) never trust someone whose first language was Hungarian about questions of where to put the stress. (2) I probably *do* say /mid-WIFE-ery/ by extrapolation, and I don't know if I've ever heard anyone else say this word, in whatever pronunciation. (When I say "I say", I mean of course my mental voice: it's just not a word that pops up in everyday conversation.)

Comment: @Martha: Sorry, I must have misremembered. I though you'd said once before that your first language was English. Not that you'd be particularly likely to learn the pronunciation of a word like *midwifery* by hearing it in ordinary domestic conversations as a child, as you say. I'm used to it because my ex was Director of Nursing at the local hospital, and Midwifery was one of the departments she was responsible for. But I have a brother who lived in Zambia from age 25-45, and even today he still comes out with oddball pronunciations that he **read**, rather than **heard**. It's easy done!

Comment: (it was a long time before I realised that I couldn't use caTHOLic/CAtholic to distinguish between the "wide-ranging/religious sect" meanings, and I still think it's a shame we don't! :)

Comment: @Fumble, no need to live in Zambia: oddball pronunciations caused by a high reading:speaking vocabulary ratio are a widespread affliction among nerd- and geek-dom. A friend of ours, who doesn't have the excuse of having learned Hungarian first (or ever), loves to drive people nuts by saying /THER-mo-meet-er/, by analogy with /THER-mo-stat/.

Comment: @Martha: "drive people nuts" - that rings a bell! My father (Lancastrian, which barely even counts as "native speaker" to most Brits! :) didn't know the word *cache* at all until his 60s, when he came across it in a book. Even now in his 90s he still pronounces it CAKE (facetiously, admittedly, since it's become a "family joke"). I don't know if he knows the word *cachet*. But I imagine if he does, and if he ever gets a chance to use it in conversation, his pronunciation will have - shall we say - a certain "cachet" (and you can say that how you will! :).

Comment: wifery: trisyllabic laxing, hence a short vowel; wife: open-syllable lengthening, hence a long vowel, followed by the great vowel shift.

Answer (score 5):

Alexander Ellis<sup>†</sup> claims that the modern pronunciation [midwaif] is “orthographical”:

> -*wife*, midwife housewife goodwife. Here orthographical readers say (m*i*⋅dwə′*i*f ʜə*u*⋅swə′*i*f g*u*:d wə′*i*f). But (m*i*⋅d*i*f) is more common, and no actor would speak otherwise in describing Queen Mab, RJ 1, 4, 23 (717,54). The thread-and-needle-case is always called a (ʜəz⋅*i*f), and the word (ʜə⋅z*i*), now spelled *hussy*, shews the old disuse of (w), and similarly (g*u*⋅d*i*), now written *goody*. (1165)  —*On Early English Pronunciation*, Pt IV (1874), 1165

Though the pronuncitation ['mɪdɪf] (in modern notation) is ignored by most old dictionaries, it is acknowledged here and there. *Routledge's Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language*, 1867, gives two pronunciations, “*mid′wif*, or *mid′wīf* ”, and Walker, *Critical Pronouncing Dictionary*, 1791, gives

> **MIDWIFERY,** mid’-wif-re, *s* 144 … Though the *i* is long in *Midwife*, it is always ſhort in its derivative *Midwifery*, and the compound *Manmidwife*.

And “144” refers to this note:

> 144. Thoſe ending in *ife*, have the *i* long, except *houſewife*, pronounced *huzzif*, according to the general rule, notwithſtanding the *i* in *wife* is always long. *Midwife* is ſometimes ſhortened in the ſame manner by the vulgar. (42)

*OED 1* (1906) says “the colloquial pronunciation (mi⋅dif) is now seldom heard.”

It appears that at least by Modern English the secondary stress on the second syllable of *midwife* had been reduced in non-educated speech to non-stress. This may have been the case even earlier, since Middle English spellings indicate that a variant was then current with the same connective vowel between the first and last syllables which gave rise to the /ɪf/ pronunciation in [*housewife*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95737/24489) and *goodwife*. Alternately, the reduction may have come about by analogy with *housewife* and *goodwife*.

“Polite” usage eventually succeeded in stamping out the “vulgar” pronunciation of *midwife*; but it may be suspected that ['mɪdɪfrɪ] was acceptable under the principle of [trisyllabic laxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing).

---

<sup>†</sup> Prototype of Shaw's Henry Higgins and inventor of the IPA characters **ʃ** and **ʒ** (along with several other notations which have not survived)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, both pronunciations are correct. Native speakers of English determine meaning and pronunciation. This descriptive approach irritates prescriptive linguists, but it usually prevails.

Comment: Hello, Don. The descriptivist argument ("That's the way people do it") is hardly novel on ELU.  This would perhaps make a reasonable 'comment', but John Lawler's 'comment' is a fine answer.

Answer (score 1):

The stress and reduction depends on the length of the word as well as common practice.
Compare **pho**to**graph** with pho**tog**ra**phy**.